# execute Ant from docker-compose

Tags: docker, ant, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm a newbie with docker.

I'm creating a dockerfile, and want to execute hello world from Ant file "build.xml"  with docker commands. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Ammar Chebbi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what you've already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick solution:

1. create a folder "ant"
2. create a file ant/Dockerfile with the contents

```
FROM alpine

WORKDIR /work

RUN apk update && apk add openjdk8 && apk add apache-ant

ENTRYPOINT [ "ant" ]
```

3. create a file ant/build.xml with the contents (I know you can do better than this but I can't :) )

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<project name = "Hello World Project" default = "info">
   <target name = "info">
      <echo>Hello World - Welcome to Apache Ant!</echo>
   </target>
</project>
```

4. build the docker image

```
docker build -t ant:1.0 ./ant
```

5. run the ant build

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/ant:/work ant:1.0
```

Of course you can put in "ant" your whole project and build that.

This can be refined, but hopefully it answers your question so far.

Answer (score 0):

@Mihai's answer seems right but there was something I needed to add because I got an error like this:

```
 > [3/3] RUN apk update && apk add openjdk8 && apk add apache-ant:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#6 0.239 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#6 0.482 139776850742088:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:                                                                                                                                                                            
#6 0.484 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: Permission denied                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#6 0.484 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: No such file or directory
```

I had to do what I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201209/docker-build-using-ca-trust-bundle-from-host).

1. Create a `repositories` file with these contents:

   ```
   http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main
   http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community
   ```
2. In `Dockerfile` before the `RUN apk update` add the following:

   ```
   COPY repositories /etc/apk/repositories
   ```