# Docker Build using CA Trust Bundle from Host

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, ssl, certificate

Given a simple Dockerfile that installs from something from the net, I'm trying to work out an elegant way to allow the build process to trust HTTPS endpoints when the build is both behind a corporate proxy and when it is not.  ***Ideally without making changes to the Dockerfile.***

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update -v; apk add -v curl
```

Error:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  83.97kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> e50c909a8df2
Step 2/2 : RUN apk update -v; apk add -v curl
 ---> Running in 983ed3885376
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
140566353398600:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: No such file or directory
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
140566353398600:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:
ERROR: 2 errors; 14 distinct packages available
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: No such file or directory
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
139846303062856:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: No such file or directory
139846303062856:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:
ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: Permission denied
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: No such file or directory
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  curl (no such package):
    required by: world[curl]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk update -v; apk add -v curl' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The issue here is that my developer machine is on the corporate network behind a traffic-intercepting proxy that man-in-the-middles the connection meaning from apk's point of view inside the Docker build, it is seeing a cert which has been signed by our proxy that it doesn't trust.

Trust from the host machine is not an issue - when I wget the file requested in the build it works:

```
$ wget https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
--2021-02-15 12:41:59--  https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
Connecting to 10.0.2.2:9000... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 631235 (616K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘APKINDEX.tar.gz’
```

When I run it on the build server it passes fine cause no forward proxy.

Is there a way to pass in the Ubuntu trust bundle which has the proxy CA's (e.g. `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates`) to the build process without modifying the Dockerfile?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi ! I have the same error. Did you find a solution ? Thanks

Comment: I think it is just a limitation of how Docker works. The operating system that is running the build needs to be able to trust the proxy certs.  Docker doesn't provide a mechanism other than using COPY to put the CA certs for your proxy into the OS, then use update-ca-certificates for Debian/Ubuntu (or equivalent) to load them into the OS trust bundle.

I think the best thing to do is to produce a base image with your CA certs in the trust bundle already then use that instead of using a base image without those certs.

Comment: This is very strange because I didn't have the problem before. I think I haven't the same error as you :
`fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz`

`ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main: Permission denied`

`fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz`

`ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community: Permission denied`

`v3.13.2-8-g7bb1c88019 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main]`

`v3.13.2-12-gea23800845 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community]`

Comment: I solved my issue. I don't know if it is the best approach but you can follow it. Copy your proxy to your image `COPY proxy.pem /opt`. Copy the same pem file to certs `COPY proxy.pem /etc/ssl/certs`. Append the cert to ca-certificates.crt. `cat /opt/proxy.pem >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Answer (score 19):

Create a file named `repositories` in your local docker build context directory with the following content:

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community
```

In your docker build file, **before** `RUN apk update`, add the following line:

```
COPY repositories /etc/apk/repositories
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM abdennour/alpine:3.14-ssl

RUN openssl x509 -inform der -in COMPANY.der -out /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/company-cert.crt && \
   cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/company-cert.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt && \
   update-ca-certificates
```

**EXPLAINED!**

1. Request the CA certificate from the team who purchased the SSL Certificates.
   Tell them provide me the certificate file "*.der"
2. Got it ? convert it to .cert file

```
RUN openssl x509 -inform der -in COMPANY.der -out /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/company-cert.crt && \
   cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/company-cert.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt && \
   update-ca-certificates
```

But this requires to have `openssl ca-certificates` packages in the image.
And because you can't install anything, then you can rely on alpine image which includes at least these two packages, like my base image:

`FROM abdennour/alpine:3.14-ssl`